# Generic method invokation with no parameter

Tags: java

If i have a generic method

```
public <T> ArrayList<T> test(){ return new ArrayList<T>(); }
```

And invoke him without explicit type parameter then will be returned raw type `ArrayList`, thus if we invoked generic method without type parameter we are invoked just corresponding non-generic method. Is it true?

Comment: Your method lacks a `return` statement.

Comment: @Holger Thakns, Edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you are allowed to invoke the method without an explicit type parameter, that means that the compiler was able to infer the appropriate type for you. That means an `ArrayList<WhateverInferredType>` will be returned.

Comment: Thus line `ArrayList<String> t= test()` equivalent to `ArrayList<String> t= Main.<String>test()`?

Answer (score 0):

No.  This method is always called with a type paramater, and the `ArrayList` will always have a type paramter.  The parameter is determined via [type inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html). In the most basic case (i. e. just calling the method), the type parameter will be `Object`.